# What is the definition of oblique spherical triangle?

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

What is the formal definition of an oblique spherical triangle?

Comment: From [the very first link when Googling *oblique spherical triangle*](http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/spherical-trigonometry/oblique-spherical-triangle): "Spherical triangles are said to be oblique if none of its included angle is 90° or two or three of its included angles are 90°. Spherical triangle with only one included angle equal to 90° is a right triangle."

Comment: Thank you. It was also the definition I found but I don't actually rely on one definition in the net. I tried to look for other definition but I think there were only few sites.

Comment: I also notice that the definition that you site is somehow confusing Sir.

Comment: Oblique triangles are triangles that are not right.  I.e. the ones that don't have exactly one right angle.  They can be further classified as acute or obtuse depending on whether they have an obtuse angle or not. [Source](https://archive.org/stream/textbookonspheri033273mbp/textbookonspheri033273mbp_djvu.txt)